# can python multiprocessing do semaphores between "unrelated" processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am looking at the multiprocessing python module to protect some hardware (memory mapped) resources which requires atomic access (to do some stuff).
(The hardware is an FPGA implementing some finite state machine, and that machine should be returned to idle before any other access could start...)

The SW which may want to access this resource are run as different linux processes, written in Python, some of them using threads (and hence using the threading module).
These processes are not spawn from a common python parent: they are typically run as deamons and also run from the command line interface.

In the C world, I would typically use a linux named semaphore to guarantee atomicity towards my HW. I don't fully understand from the multiprocessing module documentation if the equivalent functionality can be achieved (and how). Or does multiprocessing only handles locks for processes spawned (forked) from a common single program who creates the lock before forking...

So the question is really if the multiprocessing module can be used to handle synchronization between unrelated (i.e. not having any common python ancestor) processes, as linux named semaphore would? If so, how... if not, what is the best alternative...

Comment: Shall I understand that the processing module won't give me any help, then? I am a bit surprised I don't see any standard module for the POSIX interface. But using fifos could be a work-around, indeed.

Comment: A fifo (named pipe) is a good choice but AFAIK is not available on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is really if the *multiprocessing* module can be used to handle synchronization between unrelated (i.e. not having any common python ancestor) processes

**No**

Python only provides synchronization primitives which are shared via inheritance. (When using a spawning context this may be implemented via a named resource, however this is not exposed to the user.)

On linux you can use something like [`posix-ipc`](https://pypi.org/project/posix-ipc/), which provides the ability to create and open named semaphores, shared memory, and message queues.

I'm not aware of a Windows equivalent other than to use `pywin32` or even `ctypes` to call something like [`CreateSemaphoreExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphoreexa). According to the documentation it will not only need a common name in order to be shared but also be created with the appropriate security access rights.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how a named pipe (FIFO) could be used to control the flow of multiple processes.

In this case the processes share a common ancestor but that doesn't matter. The processes that are accessing the named pipe could have different parents.

Here we create the FIFO and start two processes. Each process needs to be able to read one byte from the FIFO in order to proceed with its work.

Note how the FIFO must be unbuffered and therefore also in binary mode (you can't have unbuffered text mode).

The two subprocesses are identical in this case. They open the FIFO and try to read one (unbuffered) byte. If the FIFO is still open but is empty then the read will block indefinitely.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import mkfifo, unlink, getpid, path
from tempfile import gettempdir

FIFO = path.join(gettempdir(), "_fifo_")

def target():
    with open(FIFO, "rb", 0) as fifo:
        print(fifo.read(1))
    print(getpid(), "Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        mkfifo(FIFO)
        (proc1 := Process(target=target)).start()
        (proc2 := Process(target=target)).start()
        with open(FIFO, "wb", 0) as fifo:
            fifo.write(b"12")
            proc1.join()
            proc2.join()
    finally:
        unlink(FIFO)
```

**Output:**

```
b'1'
b'2'
3181 Done
3182 Done
```